# Visual Studio 2013: how to show active file in solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

During debug I can navigate far away from first file. It's usually useful to open solution explorer tree and check current opened file siblings. Is there shortcut to open current file in solution explorer?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The feature is called Sync with Active Document. I don't have the IDE installed on the machine but I believe the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>

[Sync with Active Document button in Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJwOU.png)

Comment: What about on Mac?

Answer (score 32):

you can try this, imho sometimes it is buggy but it works most of the time

go to **Tools**, then **option**. Click **Project and Solution**. now tick the checkbox named "**Track Active Item in Solution Explorer**"

now when you are navigate to a file, the tree will follow.

Comment: On VS2015 you can go to the 'Quick Launch' at the top right and start typing 'track active'. A mnemonic I use to remember how to do this quickly is 'Speeding up the Visual Studio train can be tricky, but with the Track Active for a Quick Launch, the solution becomes obvious'

Comment: This is even better than resharper location file in solution explorer